# C# WPF - button picture looks differently on Windows 7 and Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I am trying to build application which has some pictures drawn on buttons. Application looks nice on Windows 7 - as expected, although on Windows 10 it looks differently.

Despite Defined width and height size, image is truncated.

Uploaded screens:

[1: Windows 7 vs. Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvXkt.png)

[image: Windows 7 vs. Windows 10[1]]

[2: Windows 7 vs. Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kC26.png)

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kC26.png)

```
<Menu x:Name="menu" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="_Soubor" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <MenuItem Click="NewCalculation_Click">
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="_Nová kalkulace" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="graphics/icons/new.ico" Height="35" Width="35" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Click="saveCalculation_Click">
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Uložit kalkulaci" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="graphics/icons/save.ico" Height="35" Width="35"  />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Click="LoadCalculation_Click">
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Načíst kalkulaci" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="graphics/icons/load.ico" Height="35" Width="35" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Click="createReport_Click">
                        <MenuItem.Header >
                            <TextBlock Text="Vytvoř report" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="graphics/icons/report.ico" Height="35" Width="35"  />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Click="endApp_Click">
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Konec" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="graphics/icons/close.ico" Height="35" Width="35"  />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Nastavení" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="MenuSqlSetting" Header="_Připojení na SQL server" Click="MenuSqlSetting_Click"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_O aplikaci" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
            </Menu>
```

Code for second screen:

```
<Button x:Name="buttonRemove" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="2,0,0,0" IsEnabled="False" Click="buttonRemove_Click" Background="White">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="Graphics/remove.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this article before trying anything. It's all about the theme difference between win 7 and win 10.

https://arbel.net/2006/11/03/forcing-wpf-to-use-a-specific-windows-theme/

Comment: After changing theme to PresentationFramework.Aero it has solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is another workaround from Visual Studio.
You click with the mouse on the `MenuItem` and you look at the Template in the Property Inspector under the Miscellaneous group.
Then you "Convert to New Resource..."

[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0InLD.jpg)

so you will get the corresponding xaml transformed as

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding YourCmd}" Header="Your Header" 
    Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}" >
```

Then you can build on your Windows 7 machine and deploy to Windows 10 without such issue.